# Mediawiki on AIX, PHP-component missing

Tags: aix, mediawiki

My OS-Version is AIX 7.2.5.3 (`oslevel -s` shows "7200-05-03-2148") and i try to install a Mediawiki (1.39.1). I used the RPM-packages from the "[AIX Toolbox for Open Source Software](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-overview)" and have installed the versions from there:

PHP 7.4.33
MariaDB 10.4.26
Apache 2.4.54

Now, Mediawiki complains on its configuration screen about missing PHP components, namely "intl", the internationalization functions. Alas, the only way to get this extension seems to be to compile PHP from source - a process i'd like to avoid because on AIX this is a PITA.

So, my question is: is there a known way to install Mediawiki on AIX without having to compile software? I have searched the net and came up blank, save for "`[Install Mediawiki on AIX][2]`", an article i wrote myself 10 years ago. Although working, these are versions too old to use any more.